# Update en tabla a partir de dato de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Les comento:

Tengo dos tablas tablas unidas por una llave como se ve en la imagen , y quiera hacer un update de los campos diseño,storie,texto,vb,fb y ig pero consultado el campo nombre de la otra tabla a través de la llave foránea.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
update actividades 
set diseno='"+ dato +"' 
where actividades.fk_clientes='"+nombre+"'"
```

Comment: Te podemos apoyar pero por favor agrega lo que has intentado

Comment: Muchas gracias , ahora lo edite , creo que debería hacer un join cierto ?Disculpa lo poco me cuesta aun el tema de las consultas .

Answer (score 2):

Dado que tienes una llave primaria y una foránea, lo puedes resolver del siguiente modo:

- Indiques que actualizarás la tabla actividades
- Inmediatamente después estableces la vinculación por medio de `INNER JOIN` con clave primari y foránea
- Posterior con la sentencia `SET` estableces todas las columnas que deseas actualizar igualandolas con el valor respectivo

Código:

```
UPDATE actividades
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.idclientes = actividades.fk_clientes
SET actividades.diseno = algo1,
    actividades.storie = algo2,
    actividades.texto  = algo3,
    actividades.vb     = algo4,
    actividades.fb     = algo5,
    actividades.ig     = algo6
WHERE clientes.nombre = otroAlgo;
```

Comment: Entiendo pero como lo hago si el nombre es "nombre 1" , al final debería poner una condición : Where clientes.nombre= "nombre1" . ?

Comment: Listo @IgnacioAntonioParada Editado espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono , te lo agradezco un montón.